# How to fix my headphones

Tags: headphones

An earpiece of my iPhone headphones felt into a glass of water for 10 seconds last week.

Now the sound volume form both earpieces is lower and it seems the basses are not that strong anymore.

Is there something I can do to fix my headphones or I can only throw them away ? Also, why both headpieces are now damaged if only one ended up in the water ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather throw them away. There are a few [Youtube videos](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&q=iphone+headphone+repair&oq=iphone+headphone+repair&aq=f&aqi=p-p1g1g-K1g-mK1g-b1g-bK5&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..35i39j0j0i30j0i5i30j0i8j0i8i30l5.246344.246977.0.247301.2.2.0.0.0.0.75.145.2.2.0...0.0.xJtZF7CyLS8) that could help, though.

The one which felt into the glass of water was, perhaps, the right one? I don't know why, or if it is just mine (and my mother's, actually) but it seems that the left one sounds a lot lower than the right one.

It seems, too, that Apple is quite nice about replacing the headphones while under warranty. It's worth trying, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no saving them. I would definitely suggest just buying a new pair.

Comment: This is not a very good answer and doesn't help the OP (who posted this 3 years ago) or others with a similar issue.